# how to make combination of values in a string using scala?

Tags: scala, collections, combinations, scala-collections

I want to combine the values in a string.
for example,

```
Let A = a,b,c,d
```

I want the combination as,

```
AComb = a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,abc,abd,bcd,acd
```

Comment: `Let A = a,b,c,d`?? you mean `val A =Set("a","b","c","d")`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i am Assuming that `A` is a `Set`

```
scala> val A =Set("a","b","c","d")
A: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b, c, d)


scala> val AComb=A.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector
AComb: Vector[String] = Vector("", a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, abc, abd, acd, bcd, abcd)
```

i am thinking that you didn't need that first element so you can try

```
scala> val AComb=A.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector.tail
AComb: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, abc, abd, acd, bcd, abcd)
```

removing first and last element

```
scala> val AComb=A.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector.init.tail
AComb: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, abc, abd, acd, bcd)
```

updated according to comment

```
scala> val xc1=Set("sunny","hot","high","FALSE","no")
xc1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(sunny, FALSE, hot, no, high)

scala> val AComb=xc1.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString(" ")).toVector.tail;
AComb: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(sunny, FALSE, hot, no, high, sunny FALSE, sunny hot, sunny no, sunny high, FALSE hot, FALSE no, FALSE high, hot no, hot high, no high, sunny FALSE hot, sunny FALSE no, sunny FALSE high, sunny hot no, sunny hot high, sunny no high, FALSE hot no, FALSE hot high, FALSE no high, hot no high, sunny FALSE hot no, sunny FALSE hot high, sunny FALSE no high, sunny hot no high, FALSE hot no high)
```

Comment: How to delete the last element? I only need n-1 combination

Comment: Error:(144, 28) type arguments [String] do not conform to method toSet's type parameter bounds [B >: Any]
      val AComb = xc1.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector.init.tail
                           ^

Comment: I declare my set as Set[Any], that was the problem. So I change it into Set[String]. BUt it return null value, ie. ()

Comment: My set xc1 is Set(sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no), If I apply this val AComb = xc1.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector.tail, the result is Vector(sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no)....., It doesn't gv any combination.

Comment: sir,My set xc1 is Set(sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no), If I apply this val AComb = xc1.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector.tail, the result is Vector(sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no)....., It doesn't gv any combination.

Comment: Sir, If I gave Set("a","b","c","d") like this, it will give the correct answer. But my initial row is row1 = sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no, So I convert it into set,ie.A = mutable.Set(row1) therefore,xc1 =Set(sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no).THen I apply your code to xc1, but it doen't work...

Comment: @rosy you mean  row1 = "sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no", its a string like this?

and can you put your original piece of code

Comment: val config = new SparkConf().setAppName("Apriori_Algo").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(config)
val data = sc.textFile("/home/data/weather.csv").cache()
val eachline = data.flatMap(line => line.split("/n"))
var rowelemset : scala.collection.Set[String] = null
val rowlist = eachline.map(x2 => {
rowelemset = mutable.Set(x2)
rowelemset
}
).collect()
rowlist.foreach(i => println(i))
val st = rowlist.map(xc1 => {
val AComb = xc1.toSet[String].subsets.map(_.mkString).toVector.tail
AComb                     }
    )
    st.foreach(println)